# How to build a standalone / framework agnostic web component widget to use in any web app?

Tags: reactjs, angular, npm, dependencies, web-component

I would like to build a complicated web component that:

- I Can use in my legacy web site (or any other site)
- It can be used weather my web site is built with Angular/Angular2/React/Jquery etc...
- I can use any technology to build it Angular/Angular2/React etc...
- Avoid dependencies & versioning collisions (i.e my component is built with Angular 1.5.6 and the implementing website has Angular 1.4.7)

Would using NPM module could solve this issue (versioning, depenencies etc..) ?

**Edit: (example)**

For example i would require my component via npm 
which has the dependency (requires) the framework i chose (i.e angular 1.5.6)

in this scenario wouldn't my component code use my dependency from NPM (regardless what the site uses)?

Comment: To make it truly framework agnostic, wouldn't it be sensible to make your component as a web component, rather than an angular component? That way you won't have to download the entirety of angular for every site that uses your component. MDN article on web components here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components

Comment: i dont want to be dependent on the existing site technology. for example i would like to have the option to write the new component with angular2. notice that if the website updates its framework to angular2 i wouldnt want some versioning issues. any idea how do i prevent them from happening ?

Comment: That's what I'm trying to say - if you don't want it to be dependent on existing site technology *and* you don't want conflicting versioning issues, surely it would be easier to make a component from just html/css/js, no frameworks? NPM doesn't seem to be able to install mutliple versions of one dependency in a package.json file, so avoiding versioning issues there would be difficult. Vanilla web components are entirely website independent and sound like what you're looking for, even with the extra work to make your component not use angular.

Comment: I've edited the question. i'm trying to find a way of not using vanilla js for my component.

Answer (score 0):

1. You may use a component built with angular on a legacy site but you must load angular before. You should be aware of name collision you might have with other directories.
2. If the site is already built with angular 1.x you may just blend your component in, considering that your component is compatible to the angular version the site is using.If it is not, I think react can be possible because it may blend in.
3. In case the site is built with angular 1.4.7, as you have said, you might need to downgrade your component to be used by 1.4.7. This means that if you're using angular.module(...).component you will need to switch it to directive. Alternatively you may switch the site to work with 1.5 if it is possible. If not, you may go back to react.
4. If you want to use angular 2.0, you may do so side by side with angular 1.x, however, the legacy application needs to be bootstraped with angular upgrade module, using upgradeAdapter. This means you need to interfere with the application, which you don't want to, if I understand you correctly.

Comment: i've added an example to the original question on this issue.
i'm trying to be agnostic to what the site uses. would npm be able to solve the dependecy/versioning issues ?

Comment: Doing something similar here (The question is tied to the github repository): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65159018/creating-a-standalone-web-component-build-using-as-an-iife